# Is this angular component implemented in a reactive way?

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'm starting with reactive programming and I have the following application:
[image: Test app]

The three dotted items is a `<ul>` tag. Each time a `li` item is clicked, the app navigates to a route using the routerLink appending a query string (**/bands, /bands?active=false and /bands?active=true**).

The part of the web page starting at Bands (belong to the component called **band-list**) is the content the router-outlet displays according to the route. The grid below is loaded according to the query param 'active'. Then, each time a `li` item is clicked, the grid reloads.

Also, the **Refresh data button** reloads the grid.

I'm trying to implement, using reactive programming, the following logic:

- At initialization, the `band-list` component should load the grid according to the `active` query parameter in the route.
- Each time the user clicks a `li`, the grid should reload. If previous to this click on a `li` the grid is still loading (making an http request), the http request in progress should be cancelled (this looks to me like a `switchMap` operator).
- If the user clicks the `refresh data button` and the grid has finished loading its data, the grid should load. However, if the grid is still loading its data (in the middle of an http request), the click should do nothing, i.e., the in-process loading data operation should finished, and the click in the button is practically ignored (this looks like an `exhaustMap` to me :S)
- Also, each time an http operation is performed, a message telling "Loading..." should show up while the http operation has no finished, and the data in the grid should be emptied. When the http request finishes, the "Loading..." message should be removed and the data should show up in the grid.

I implemented the code in the `band-list` component like this next code block, but I'm not sure about the use of the `defer` operator for my solution. I used the `defer` operator since I need to maintain the state if a current request is in process with the `isLoading` variable inside the defer operator, and also updating this variable as a side-effect action in the `tap` operator, and using this variable as a side-effect in the `filter` operator.

**My question is: is this a nice way to do it according to reactive programming? What could I do better?**

You can check this solution in [this stackblitz' url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vmhsqo?file=migration%2FREADME.md)

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-band-list',
    templateUrl: 'band-list.component.html',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class BandListComponent {
    readonly initialState: BandState = { data: [], isLoading: false };
    #bandDataService = inject(BandDataService);

    refreshDataClickSubject = new Subject<void>();
    #activedRoute = inject(ActivatedRoute);

    bandState$;

    constructor() {
        this.bandState$ = this.getBands$();

        const destroyRef = inject(DestroyRef);
        destroyRef.onDestroy(() => {
            this.refreshDataClickSubject.complete();
            this.refreshDataClickSubject.unsubscribe();
        });
    }

    getBands$(): Observable<BandState> {
        const queryParams$ = this.#activedRoute.queryParams;
        const refreshDataClick$ = this.refreshDataClickSubject.asObservable();

        const isActiveFromQueryParams$ = queryParams$.pipe(
            map<any, boolean | undefined>(p => p["active"])
        );

        const final$ = defer(() => {
            let isLoading = false;

            const getBandsFn$ = (isActive: boolean | undefined) => concat(
                of([]).pipe(
                    tap(_ => isLoading = true), // <== here updating the outer state. 
                    map(data => ({data, isLoading: true}))
                ),
                this.#bandDataService.getBands$(isActive).pipe(
                    map(data => ({data, isLoading: false}))
                )
            ).pipe(
                finalize(() => isLoading = false) // <== again updating the outer state.
            );

            const obs$ = merge(
                queryParams$.pipe(map(_ => RequestOrigin.QueryParams)),
                refreshDataClick$.pipe(map(_ => RequestOrigin.RefreshButton))
            ).pipe(
                filter(requestOrigin => requestOrigin === RequestOrigin.QueryParams ||
                    (requestOrigin === RequestOrigin.RefreshButton && !isLoading)),
                withLatestFrom(isActiveFromQueryParams$),
                map(([_, isActive]) => isActive),
                switchMap(isActive => getBandsFn$(isActive)),
                startWith(this.initialState)
            );
            return obs$;
        });

        return final$;
    }
}

enum RequestOrigin {
    QueryParams, RefreshButton
}

interface BandState {
    data: Band[],
    isLoading: boolean
}
```

```
<h2>Bands</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" (click)="refreshDataClickSubject.next()">
                Refresh data
            </button>
        </div>

        @if(bandState$ | async; as bandState) {
            @if (bandState.isLoading) {
                Loading...
            } @else {
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Formation year</th>
                            <th>Is active</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @for(band of bandState.data; track $index) {
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ band.name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ band.formationYear }}</td>
                                <td>{{ band.isActive }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        } @empty {
                            <h3>Empty!</h3>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            }
        } @else {
            BandState$ not initialized
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your current StackBlitz throws some errors, since some code is missing. E.g. `bands$`observable missing in band-data.service, which your are trying to access in line 74 of band-list.component. Same with `isActiveChanged`. Could you please update your code.

Comment: I am also getting error while running StackBlitz. Can you please check and update with working demo.

Comment: @JB17 sorry, the code was fix

Comment: @RohìtJíndal sorry, the code was fix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a much simpler way to achieve your desired behavior.  But first, let's start with a very basic implementation that gets you 90% there:

```js
private isActive$ = inject(ActivatedRoute).queryParamMap.pipe(
  map(params => params.get('active'))
);

bandState$: Observable<BandState> = this.isActive$.pipe(
  switchMap(isActive => this.#bandDataService.getBands$(isActive).pipe(
    map(data => ({ data, areBandsLoading: false })),
    startWith({ data: [], areBandsLoading: true })
  ))
);
```

`isActive$` is an observable that emits the value of the query param. When it emits the value, we `switchMap` to the call to get the data.  We then `map` the result from the api call to your `BandState` shape.  Lastly, we specify an initial value to emit using `startWith` just like you've already done in your code.

This means that whenever the query param changes, a call will be made to get the appropriate data and the `bandState$` observable will emit the updated state.

The reason I show this simple implementation first is because it is not too far from the solution that gets you the "refresh" behavior that you want.

---

In order to incorporate your "refresh" functionality, we can use a `BehaviorSubject` as a notification trigger.

```js
refresh$ = new BehaviorSubject<void>(undefined);
```

Then, instead of piping the `isActive$` emission directly to the http call, we will send it to this intermediate trigger, then use `exhaustMap` to handle the call. The reason we use `BehaviorSubject` instead of `Subject` is so we receive an emission upon subscription, meaning our `switchMap` doesn't need to wait for `refresh$` to be triggered the first time, it happens automatically:

```js
bandState$: Observable<BandState> = this.isActive$.pipe(
  switchMap(isActive => this.refresh$.pipe(
    exhaustMap(() => this.#bandDataService.getBands(isActive).pipe(
      map(data => ({ data, areBandsLoading: false })),
      startWith({ data: [], areBandsLoading: true })
    ))
  ))
);
```

Check out this working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-77822864?devtoolsHeight=50&file=src%2Fband-data.service.ts,src%2Fband-list%2Fband-list.component.html,src%2Fband-list%2Fband-list.component.ts)

Comment: isLoading gonna stay true in case of error

Comment: true, this is just a simple implementation, but handling the error could easily be added.

Comment: This is the beauty of the reactive paradigm, conciseness

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for! First, I wasn't sure if I should have designed the template with one or 2 observables: one observable emitting the band data and the loading message; or 2 observables, one emitting the band data and another one for the message data.
I should say, also, your pipeline is really clever. I didn't think of that solution. Certainly, I must train more in reactive programming.

Answer (score 0):

We can take two streams, apply the `switchMap` and `exhaustMap` and use `merge` the results, we can use a merge with `of(null)` so we can trigger the API on load itself!

fakeService

```
import { Injectable, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { delay, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Band } from './model';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/co mmon/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class BandDataService {
  http = inject(HttpClient);

  getBands$(active?: boolean): Observable<Band[]> {
    console.log(active);
    const params = new HttpParams().set(
      'active',
      active === undefined ? '' : active
    );
    return this.http.get<Band[]>('https://dummyjson.com/products/1').pipe(
      map(() => ([
        {
          id: '1',
          bio: 'asdf',
          name: 'test',
          formationYear: 2022,
          isActive: true,
        },
        {
          id: '1',
          bio: 'asdf',
          name: 'test',
          formationYear: 2022,
          isActive: false,
        },
      ])),
      delay(3000),
    );

    // return of([]).pipe(delay(1_000));
  }

  updateIsActive(id: string, isActive: boolean) {
    return of([]);
    // console.log(`Setting isActive to ${isActive} for band with id ${id}`);
    // const band = this.bands.find(band => band.id === id)!;
    // band.isActive = isActive;
    // return of({ ...band }).pipe(
    //  delay(1000)
    // );
  }
}
```

ts

```
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Component,
  DestroyRef,
  inject,
} from '@angular/core';
import { BandDataService } from '../band-data.service';
import {
  BehaviorSubject,
  Observable,
  Subject,
  combineLatest,
  concat,
  defer,
  filter,
  finalize,
  iif,
  map,
  merge,
  of,
  startWith,
  switchMap,
  tap,
  withLatestFrom,
} from 'rxjs';
import { Band } from '../model';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { concatMap, exhaustMap, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-band-list',
  templateUrl: 'band-list.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class BandListComponent {
  bandDataService = inject(BandDataService);

  refreshDataClickSubject = new Subject<string>();
  activedRoute: ActivatedRoute = inject(ActivatedRoute);

  bandState$;
  isActive!: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.bandState$ = this.getBands$();
  }

  getBands$(): Observable<Band[] | null> {
    const queryParams$ = this.activedRoute.queryParams;
    const refreshDataClick$ = this.refreshDataClickSubject.asObservable();

    const isActiveFromQueryParams$: Observable<boolean> = queryParams$.pipe(
      map((p: Params) => {
          const active = p['active'] === 'true';
          this.isActive = active;
          return active;
      }),
    );

    const getBandsFn$ = () =>
      merge(of(null), this.bandDataService.getBands$(this.isActive));

    const final$ = defer(() => {
      const obs$: Observable<Band[] | null> = merge(
        isActiveFromQueryParams$.pipe(
          switchMap(() => {
            return getBandsFn$();
          })
        ),
        refreshDataClick$.pipe(
          exhaustMap(() => {
            return getBandsFn$();
          })
        ),
      );
      return obs$;
    });

    return final$;
  }
}
```

html

```
<h2>Bands</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <button
        class="btn btn-primary"
        type="button"
        (click)="refreshDataClickSubject.next('refresh')"
      >
        Refresh data
      </button>
    </div>

    @if(bandState$ | async; as bandState) {
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Formation year</th>
          <th>Is active</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @for(band of bandState; track $index) {
        <tr>
          <td>{{ band.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ band.formationYear }}</td>
          <td>{{ band.isActive }}</td>
        </tr>
        } @empty {
        <h3>Empty!</h3>
        }
      </tbody>
    </table>
    } @else { Loading... }
  </div>
</div>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jfysat?file=migration%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fband-data.service.ts,migration%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fband-list%2Fband-list.component.ts,migration%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fband-list%2Fband-list.component.html,migration%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts,migration%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,migration%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,migration%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fband-list%2Fband-list.component.css)

Comment: The idea is to use network requests to see if they are cancelled when a new request happens. In your code there is no request made and, as far as I can observe, all the previous actions for reloading are discarded due to the switchMap, but that is not the case that I need. Please, read the logic explained in my question.

Comment: yes, the latest request is the one it is needed, but read again the logic required. When there's an ongoing request that hasn't finished and the user clicks the refresh button, the action fired by the button is ignored

Comment: the problem with exhaustMap is that you don't comply with the other rule: `Each time the user clicks a li, the grid should reload. If before this click on a li the grid is still loading (making an http request), the http request in progress should be cancelled (this looks to me like a switchMap operator) and a new request should be fired.`. 
So, the answer doesn't comes down to only use one higher order observable, you have to balance up mergeMap and exhaustMap.

Comment: For you to be able to see how the http request are cancelled, it is better to try out a solution using the server that is along with the angular project. Read the README file

Answer (score 0):

A different approach with `Signals`:

Starting by declaring `bands` and `areBandsLoading` signals:

```js
protected readonly bands = signal<Band[]>([]);
protected readonly areBandsLoading = signal<boolean>(false);
```

Then we define our `fetchBands` method which returns an `Observable` (we don't subscribe here because it will be used in other observable `route.queryParamMap` to avoid nested subscribtions) and we made it `private` because it is only used inside the class:

```js
private fetchBands(active: string | null): Observable<Band[]> {
  this.areBandsLoading.set(true);
  return this.bandsService.getBands(active).pipe(
    finalize(() => this.areBandsLoading.set(false)),
    first(),
    tap((data) => this.bands.set(data))
  );
}
```

We used `finalize` to set loading state to `false` in case error happened, `first` to not keep the observale alive after fetching is done, and `tap` to set the value of bands signal.

Then we subscribe to `queryParamMap` to fetch the data when the query params change:

```js
this.route.queryParamMap
  .pipe(
    takeUntilDestroyed(),
    switchMap((map) => this.fetchBands(map.get('active')))
  )
  .subscribe();
```

We used `switchMap` to cancel the old stream completely when a new value emits, this is an optimization in case a new fetch request was made while the previous one is not done yet, it will cancel the old request (you can check it in network tab if you click on different `li` quickly in this example) and `takeUntilDestroyed` to make sure the stream is completed when the component is destroyed (prevent memory leaks).

Small note, `takeUntilDestroyed` is still in [developer preview](https://angular.io/api/core/rxjs-interop/takeUntilDestroyed)

Finally `refreshData` method is `protected` as it is used in the template outside the class and it simply read the value of active query param from the route snapshot and fetch the data again:

```js
protected refreshData(): void {
  const active = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('active');
  this.fetchBands(active).subscribe();
}
```

Check out the full code on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vergx7?file=migration%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fband-list%2Fband-list.component.ts)

Comment: Please share code and explain what it achieves, not just a link

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35560988)

Comment: My bad, thanks for pointing this out guys, will update my answer.

Comment: Really clever and interesting solution with signals, although I think you should handle the unsubscription too, right?